# AngularJS: $http.get 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, http, http-status-code-405

when I get a request from a url,like this:

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:'http://mooc-lms.dev.web.nd/v0.3/users/login'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //code
    });
```

But the error I get is:

```
    GET http://mooc-lms.dev.web.nd/v0.3/users/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

However,if I change the method from "GET" to "POST",the error is:

```
    POST http://mooc-lms.dev.web.nd/v0.3/users/login 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

What's the problem?Is there something wrong with the url(http://mooc-lms.dev.web.nd/v0.3/users/login)?  I find '"message":"Request method 'GET' not supported"' in the url.

Comment: If you have this error, it's probably because your server haven't any `GET` method implement on this url.

Comment: show us your back-end (no thats not dirty) we just need to see what your request is supposed to do. maybe you have not implemented it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that `GET` isn't working is that the server doesn't support `GET` for the login endpoint, which is unsurprising. The most common reason for getting an `HTTP 415` response on a `POST` request is because the server requires you to specify a `Content-Type` and/or `Accept` in your request header.

My example below sets them to `application/json`, which is common, but not ubiquitous, so you'll have to check what the server requires, and what it will give you back. Given that the address contains "mooc-lms", I assume you're doing some kind of online course. It should give you that information. That documentation should also tell you what data you need to send with the data property.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mooc-lms.dev.web.nd/v0.3/users/login',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', /*or whatever type is relevant */
        'Accept': 'application/json' /* ditto */
    },
    data: {
        /* You probably need to send some data if you plan to log in */
    }
})
```

Comment: I am facing the similar error. I tried your solution but it didn't work for me.
The URL gives response if I directly enter it in the url bar or through REST client also I am getting the data in the response.
My server is set with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header only impacts [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). That's a totally separate thing.

It sounds like you're not supposed to be POSTing. If you're hitting your resource through your URL bar and getting what you want, it sounds like you're just GETing.