# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, symfony

When I run http-server -o with angularjs(frontend) to use api from symfony (backend) for login, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)
>   :8080/app/api/src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController.php
>
> error Impossible d'accéder au serveur.

connection.js

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('myapplication.connection', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/connection', {
        templateUrl: 'connection/connection.html',
        controller: 'connectionCtrl'
      });}])
    .controller('connectionCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
        $http.post('api/src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController.php', {formType:'connection'})
    .then(function (response) {
            $scope.connection = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.connection = "Impossible d'accéder au serveur.";
        }); 
    }]);
```

connection.html(form)

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Connexion</h2>
    <div>{{ connection }}</div>
</div>
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend likely requires you to set Content-Type and/or Accept in your request header. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915780/angularjs-http-get-405-method-not-allowed) for example.